# Is there a way to use the selection of a listview or spinner in uri..Builder/URL

Tags: android, json, uribuilder

I am Building an app to upload images to my company server,
Now on our server there are categories(just folders) built into our file upload system
The Thing is I am going to make a listview/spinner to select the category(generated from a json) I just want to know the feasibility of using that selection and then calling the selection in Uri.builder, just need to know if it is possible before i start coding

Comment: Been Coding for android and java , coding in general for about 2 weeks now, so I wouldnt know even where to start :D @Rafsanjani

Answer (score 0):

This is Actually easily solved

So you create a String to assign to the data you will pass to the URI Builder

**Then You add Something like this to your spinner onItemSelect**

```
 Task=taskSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then in the URI Builder

you add something like this

```
.appendQueryParameter("TimeLogMinutes", minutesText.getText().toString())
```